# Django issue running manage.py on Mac

Tags: python, django, atom-editor, python-venv

I am trying to run a project in atom using a virtual environment and I keep getting an error in regards to the manage.py file.  `File "manage.py", line 17 ) from exc ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I've searched for solutions all over and most people seem to resolve it by using `python3 manage.py runserver` in the virtual environment instead of `python manage.py runserver` but that did not work for me. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: please add output of `python --version` and `pip freeze`. in Linux there is `which` command that helps to identify the exact executable when `python` is commanded. Try something like that in Mac to locate the exact python executable running.

Answer (score 2):

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

in `Mac` terminal, which works for me.

Whereas,

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

in `VS code` terminal, which doesn't work for me.

I hope it could help.

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect. python3 manage.py runserver works for me in both Mac terminal and VS code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have tried to run your Django app but you have not activated the virtual environment which you installed Django in to.

try to activate your virtual env by making sure you are in the directory of your django app in terminal/command prompt and type:

Linux:
`source nameofenv/bin/activate`

Windows:
`nameofenv\Scripts\activate`

Answer (score 0):

alias python3="/usr/bin/python3" you can used this on your mac before  python3 manage.py runserver

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).